# How do I lower the drawbridge in Geirmund's Hall?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Geirmund's hall, there is a point where I'm at a drawbridge that I can't lower.  A nearby switch triggers the traps that pop out of the wall, and I can see the two beady eyes of the wight waiting for me once I get the bridge down.  How do I do so?

There doesn't seem to be any of the obvious bird-fish-snake puzzles nearby.

Here is the screenshot of the location:

[image]

Comment: That is where i am currently stuck as well. Did you figure it out?

Comment: Oh my god. I was stuck here too, and the fact that it was that obvious pisses me off more than being stuck in the first place. lol.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

look on the wall right behind the lever that shoots the spikes. There's another lever. It's kinda hidden facing the draw bridge.

Comment: just to clarify, the lever is on the wall directly behind you when facing the same way as my screenshot.  Its over on the left side near the corner.

Comment: Oh that is just classic, I looked everywhere, but finally this handle right beside another handle!